# Use ApacheClientHttpInvoker instead of DefaultHttpInvoker

Tags: cmis, apache-chemistry

Is there any setting in Apache Chemistry to force Apache HTTP Client for connections instead of default Java HTTP functionality?

In package org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.http there is ApacheClientHttpInvoker class that does what I need but I dont know how to use it without source code modification?

I'm asking this because Lotus Notes 9 has bug in its JVM and java.net.HttpURLConnection always throws NullPointerException...

Thank you for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the session parameter HTTP_INVOKER_CLASS to "org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.http.ApacheClientHttpInvoker" and make sure that you have the Apache HTTP Client jars (tested with 4.2.5) in your classpath.

For more session parameters see:
http://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.10.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/commons/SessionParameter.html

Comment: Thank you, this works, I have modified ClientBinding source code always to use ApacheClientHttpInvoker but thats not a solution because of updates. Now I get the "Unauthorized" exception when applying credentials. This worked with the DefaultHTTPInvoker class. Am I missing something??

Comment: The ApacheClientHttpInvoker is pretty new and not very well tested. That's why you couldn't find any information about it. It might have bugs!

Having that said, basic authentication has been tested and should work without any additional configuration.

Comment: Florian, I have debuged the code with basic authentication, it works simillar (authentication) as default http. Anyways, username and password gets b64 encoded and put as http header which is then posted. This method works with default http but not with Apache http. In other project of mine I use Client.setAuth(Credentials) and that works. I can modify AbstractApache class but I do not prefer it because of forward compliance. If you are close to development team can you check this out?